# Adding a guard and provider in auth.php through serviceprovider

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, package

Laravel Version: 5.4
PHP Version: 7

I making a custom package and i'am wondering if it's possible to add a guard and provider through my ServiceProvider. I don't want that other developer need to put manually things in auth.php when they install the custom package.

So i just want to fill 'providers' and 'guard' in auth.php.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible:

In your service provider `boot()` do:

```
 Auth::provider('myprovidername',function ($app,array $config) { 
      return myproviderobject
 });

 Auth::extend("myguard", function ($app,$name, array $config) {
     return myguard;
 });
```

Whoever needs to use your auth driver can just put the following in their `config/auth.php`:

```
'guards' => [
     // ...
     'myguardconfig' => [
          'driver' => 'myguard',
          'provider' => 'myproviderconfig'
     ]
 ]

//...

 'providers' => [
         // ...
        'myproviderconfig' => [
               'driver' => 'myprovidername'
         ] 
  ]
```

Comment: is it possible to do also the last step automatically? I'am familiar with the first step. I want a clean installation guide with not to much steps :)

Comment: @matthijsneijenhuijs https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/publishing-config-and-migrations-from-included-package-in-laravel might be of help. You can write your own package config and merge it in.

Comment: Thnx, this is the solution!

[code]
        $this->mergeConfigFrom(__DIR__ . '/Config/provider.php', 'auth.providers');

        $this->mergeConfigFrom(__DIR__ . '/Config/guard.php', 'auth.guards');

[/code]

Comment: Hmmm. Nope. I'm just getting `Auth guard [icmsapi] is not defined.` :/

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a custom package, then I would recommend you to create your own config file and publish it ([check here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/packages#publishing-file-groups)). As `auth.php` is used by laravel and other packages, changing it will affect them.

Comment: I don't want to effect a existing application. Maybe the person already have a custom auth.php.

Comment: Can you please define a exact scenario?

Comment: A lot of people have already a laravel application working. I made a custom e-commerce package that not effect your existing laravel configuration / database. 

So i was thinking is it not possible to add a provider through my ServiceProvider in my package. It works now with adding this in your auth.php:
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'husers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => MyPackage\Backend\Models\User::class,
        ]